# Showing documentation in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Im new to python, but Im well familiar with other JetBrains IDE. I want to read NumPy documentation in PyCharm. after pressing ctrl+Q I get a suggestion to open external documentation, instead of providing me the existing one. How do I get PyCharm to display documentation in popup instead of suggesting me external link?

Image below shows what happens now when I press ctrl+Q on NumPy method "where". IDe suggest open external documentation, although documentation is right there visible on a screen and available.
[image: externaldocumentation]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't default to loading the local module docstring in this case. However you can load external docs inline by adding patterns to PyCharm to tell it where to find external documentation for a given module.

1. Go to Settings > Tools > Python External Documentation
2. Click Add (+) Button to add a new module to the list
3. Set module name: `numpy`, URL/Path Pattern: `https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/{element.qname}.html`
4. Click Ok and Apply
5. Now when you look up numpy docs you get everything inline

[image: Visual for the steps I mention]
[image: how it looks when you do quick docs]

Comment: Not anymore (as of Feb. 2021)

Comment: yeah looks the URL has moved :(

Comment: I would think it should be `https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.{element.name}.html` because `where` ought to be substituted for `{element.name}` to yield `https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html`.  Unfortunately, this doesn't bring up the documentation within PyCharm, regardless of the `{}` type used.  AFAIK, there is no way to see what PyCharm is actually querying on, to see if it is indeed substituting `where` for `{element.name}`.

Comment: Is there still no solution found for this? :( I even noticed when closing and opening PyCharm again, numpy is removed from the external documentation packages and the text refers to docs.scipy again, maybe this is internally saved somewhere and overwrites what is written in the external documentation?